# CodeIgniter Removing index.php using .htaccess file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Removing index.php in CodeIgniter using .htaccess file is not working for me. I Tried following code eventhough not working.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I tried this http://firstcode.info/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url/. But not working.But its working in my localhost. I also edited httpd.config file.But off no use.
Please help me.

Comment: Found this, https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter may be use full has different htaccess for you to try out.

Comment: Thankyou I got Solution

Comment: Until you learn reading apache files, google for "far in space codeigniter htaccess". Most useful example you could need and best one I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1**

Open the folder `“application/config”` and open the file `“config.php“.` find and replace the below code in `config.php file.`

*find the below code*

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"

replace with the below code

$config['index_page'] = "
```

**STEP 2**

*Write below code in .htaccess file*

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   </IfModule>
```

**STEP 3**

`“application/config/config.php“,` then find and replace the below code

*find the below code*

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"

replace with the below code

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Comment: I already tried the above code I am getting Internal Server Error

Comment: Thank you for response I got it fixed

Answer (score 1):

Your mentioned code is correct.

You have to modify apache2.conf (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf --- its my servers path) check your path.

Find this culprit `"AllowOverride None"` and `/var/www/` or `/var/www/html`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

update to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Dont forget to `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: /var/www/ also important. This path to your working directory should be correct

Comment: Thank you for response I got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php 
</IfModule>
```

In my **config.php** file ihave following settings.

```
$config['index_page']   = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

Comment: Thank you for response I got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Please try change base url as well in config.php, If using localhost or domainname.com

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/'; // localhost
```

OR

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domainname.com/'; // domainname.com
```

Answer (score 0):

add in `.htacess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$
```

remove "index.php" from `$config['index_page']` in `config.php` (keep blank value)

and fix the permission of project folder.