# Forbidden access Codeigniter URL

Tags: apache, codeigniter

I have system and application folder in `code-igniter`. Where i wrote a login form and called it from the controller.The controller is in `application/controller/main.php`. When i run the controller directly using

```
https://localhost:8080/Trainer/application/index.html/main
```

I get forbidden access  error. I have included required all granted in the Apache `httpd.conf`.

And also in many sites i have looked `code-igniter` index page is in `.php` but the default extension is in `.html`

How can i make it work?

Comment: could you post your code and did you put your files in proper location

Comment: how will you run a basic codeigniter controller?

Comment: You cannot access that URL

Comment: then how can i access it?

Comment: i think you need basic tutorials for that http://codesamplez.com/codeigniter-tutorials

Comment: I know the default controller in routes is alread set to the main only.

Comment: CI does not work that way.There are lots of protection.First there is .htaccess file inside your application folder which contains deny all. and there is also coding that says something like `! defined('BASEPATH'`

Comment: You need some more learning about Codeigniter. CI is MVC you can't directly access file form url.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `index.php` into `index.html`, in root folder (see below image).

[image: 01]

Because this files only contain the paths of `application` path and `system` paths:

```
$application_folder = 'application';
$system_path = 'system';
```

If you want to add `.html` or `.php` end of your URL, you can do it by `config.php`:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';//.html or .php
```

Answer (score -2):

According to https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html in "URI Segments" section:

"The segments in the URL, in following with the Model-View-Controller approach, usually represent:
example.com/class/function/ID

1. The first segment represents the controller class that should be invoked.
2. The second segment represents the class function, or method, that should be called.
3. The third, and any additional segments, represent the ID and any variables that will be passed to the controller.
   The URI Class and the URL Helper contain functions that make it easy to work with your URI data. In addition, your URLs can be remapped using the URI Routing feature for more flexibility."

if your web page is in "www/Trainer" location, so you access to the Main controller page:
https://localhost:8080/Trainer/index.php/main/

To remove "index.php" from all links use: [CodeIgniter Removing index.php using .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272698/codeigniter-removing-index-php-using-htaccess-file)